# First paragraph of the enumerate in bold

Tags: enumerate, bold

i want only the first paragraph of the enumerate in bold.

Today i'm doing this way:

```
\item \textbf{TEXT_HERE}
```

But i imagine there's a smarter way of doing this.

That's what i want:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does each enumerated item consist of at least two paragraphs, or could some items consist of a single paragraph?

Comment: each enumerated item consist of at least two paragraphs. I'm using the first paragraph as a reference for the question.

Comment: `\textbf` seems like the right markup.

Comment: Hi there, fellow Brazilian! `:)` You could also wrap things like `\newcommand{\mchoiceitem}[1]{\item {\bfseries(#1)}\par}`, then issue `\mchoiceitem{Petrobrás Bicombustível -- 2010 -- Administrador Júnior -- Q.\ 37} Os estoques representam ...` inside your `enumerate` environment. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on Paulo Cereda's solution that hides the details inside an environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{benumerate}{%
  \enumerate%
  \let\realItem\item%
  \def\item##1\par{\realItem\textbf{##1}\par}}%
  {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{benumerate}
    \item Some nice title

    Some nice paragraph
    \item Another nice title

    Another nice paragraph
  \end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Of course,  LaTeX will be unhappy if you don't have a paragraph break after each `\item`.

Answer (score 1):

You can package `\mdseries` into `\par`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \let\oldpar\par
        \def\par{\mdseries\oldpar}
        \def\myitem{\item\bfseries}
        \myitem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        \myitem Aenean massa.
        \myitem Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
        \myitem Nulla consequat massa quis enim. \par
        Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        \myitem enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
    \end{enumerate}
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you can make `\par` *self-healing*. Notice that I am using `textbf` but `\mdseries`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \let\oldpar\par
        \def\myitem{\item\bfseries\def\par{\mdseries\let\par\oldpar\par}}
        \myitem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
        \myitem Aenean massa.
        \myitem Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. 
        \myitem Nulla consequat massa quis enim. \par
        Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        \myitem enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
    \end{enumerate}
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
\end{document}
```